# Beginner bicyclist question about purchasing a new road bike

Tags: commuter, shopping

Completely new to biking, and am considering purchasing a decent road bike that'll be comportable for 25 mile outings. Came across a used "KHS Aero Turbo" for 325 bucks. It looks like a nice bike, but like I said, I have no experience or frame of reference for what qualifies as a decent bike. Could anyone help me out in regards to if this is worth the money, or perhaps what other brands/makes to look out for?

Thanks!

Comment: Even in great shape that is high according to this blue book.   http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=85299&make=692&model=41147&year=1999&priceMax=20000

Comment: The edited title seems to be incorrect. Isn't the question actually about purchasing a second-hand road bike (given that one of the answers says that the bike in question is at least 16 years old)?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to cycling. 325 bucks is really not too much for a complete bike (you'll understand this better later on). So, go for it as long as the sizing is correct for you. If you are not sure about sizing, take the bike to an LBS and have them do a (paid) assesment and fit in case you buy it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to some [information about the bike](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=1999&brand=KHS&model=Aero+Turbo). According to that page, that model hasn't been made since 1999 and had an original sticker price of $799. So it's at least 16 years old. Depending on what condition it's in and if any parts have been replaced or upgraded, I'd try to get the seller to bring the price down a little. That being said, it actually looks to be a pretty good bike and will be fine for 25 mile, or longer rides, as long as it fits you well.